# Where can I watch the original FUNimation dub of Dragon Ball: Curse of the Blood Rubies?

Tags: dragon-ball, dragon-ball-movies, funimation

All English dub version of *Dragon Ball: Curse of the Blood Rubies* I can find is the re-dub with the Kai voices.

The reason I want this is because it's weird to go from Stephanie as the voice of Goku on the anime to Colleen on the 1st, 2nd, 3rd *Dragon Ball* movies, and then *back to Stephanie again* on the 4th movie.

Where can I watch the original FUNimation dub of the movie?

Comment: Looking at the cast of the movie on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Ball:_Curse_of_the_Blood_Rubies#Cast), Goku wasn't voiced by Stephanie Nadolny but by Saffron Henderson. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Note that this might be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where the current question looks like asking "Where can I watch the first, already existing, FUNimation dub of the movie", but the intended question is more like "Is there a FUNimation dub of the movie with Stephanie as the voice actor?"

Comment: The movie has never released uncut in the US, nor dubbed by Funimation's in-house voice cast (It was previously dubbed by BLT Productions) until Funimation aquired the rights from Lionsgate in 2009. Saffron Henderson voiced young Goku in the prior dub iteration before the current uncut one with the Kai cast. Streaming rights for the prior versions do not exist, but you can still probably find them on VHS Or in the  "Dragon Ball: The Saga of Goku" DVD set (this version uses the BLT dub).